# "He was with us" Vs. "He was together with us"

Tags: grammar

> I was in the metro today and Jon **was with us**.

Should I add the word "**together**" to this sentence or it is grammatically correct even without it and the addition word is just a matter of emphasize and elucidation?

> I was in the metro today and Jon **was together with us**.

Comment: "X was with us" is fine. Why wouldn't it be? Adding together sounds like you speak another language, even though it is formally grammatical.

Comment: This issue wasn't clear to me. I used to say intuitively "He was with us" but later I hear someone that isn't native English speaker that said "He was **together with us**" and it made me confused and thinking maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Only the sentence "I was in the metro today and Jon was with us." is correct, do not complement it unnecessarily with "together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was in the metro today and Jon was with us.

This is correct.

> I was in the metro today and Jon was together with us.

Does not appear to be idiomatic or common English.

However, in Russian they often use a construction like "together with us." And, who knows, maybe many other world languages also have that phrase...